# Excel formula to give a certain value based on referencing 2-3 rows, help in reducing the manual work

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, automation

I am searching for the formula which looks for value"X" in the column J, if the value in J is "X" I want the formula to look into column H and refer the concerned row, the row above and beneath, to match the figure in concerned row in H, give value as "Y"; otherwise give value as blank. for eg, row/column J 54836(highlighted) has an "X"; but the column/row 54835:54836 doesn't have the value of column/row 54836(361.705,99) still the formula gives the value as "Y".

I don't want to go manually over 65000 lines to find the same figures, please help me in making my work short.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect you want to look for a match in column I otherwise K54837 shouldn't be Y either as H54837 is positive but H54838 is negative.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the logical mistake, I did adjust the formula but problem still exists=IF(J54646="X";IF(COUNTIF(I54645:I54647;I54646);"Y";"");"") I am getitng the "Y" in front of every X

Comment: So all 3 conditions are true then `y`? I would write it like this =IF(AND(J54646="X";H54645=H54646:H54647=I54646);"Y;""). NOTE your formula above is looking in Column J not H.

Comment: depending on the data you may also need to add rounding.

Comment: @Devesh if you COUNTIF any range looking to match with one of the cells within the range it will always be at least 1 because your cell is in the range you're checking against. You'll need a qualifier to say you want more than one match; so something to more like IF(COUNTIF(I54645:I54647;I54646)>1;"Y";""), or to make it clearer you want to know about the row before or after I would prefer to use something more like IF(OR(I54645=I54646; I54647=I54646);"Y";"")